# Inline Image function is not working correctly

Tags: python, templates, ms-word, jinja2, inline-images

I have written a code regarding creating context for my Word Template which is scripting by Jianjo2(I am trying to read context, that is created by python, with Jinja2 in Word). but part of image is not working.

this is how I inlined my image:

```
plot = InlineImage(tpl,path to my image', width=6, height=3)
```

I want to see the image where I wrote a code t read image i my template.